# Amazon Add Product process via Submit Feed

Tags: amazon-mws

I have professional account in seller center of Amazon. I didn't get test account, I tried to get test account (via contacting with Technical Account Management at Amazon.com) but it was unsuccessfully. So I get a credit in $40 and start trying to develop. I tried to add product by submitting feed.
The request is the next

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>A2HGOM5XPL5UHF</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>11MYSKU11</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>ASIN</Type>
                <Value>B005S25V5Z</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Example product 2</Title>
                <Brand>Example product Brand</Brand>
                <Description>A really cool product with 2 batteries and widgets</Description>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
                <PackageWeight unitOfMeasure="OZ">44</PackageWeight>
                <MSRP currency="USD">111.11</MSRP>
                <Manufacturer>ACME</Manufacturer>
                <MfrPartNumber>123456789</MfrPartNumber>
                <SearchTerms>123456789</SearchTerms>
                <SearchTerms>ACME</SearchTerms>
                <PlatinumKeywords>155385011</PlatinumKeywords>
                <ItemType>Item_Type_Enum</ItemType>
                <IsGiftWrapAvailable>false</IsGiftWrapAvailable>
                <IsGiftMessageAvailable>false</IsGiftMessageAvailable>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
            <Health>
                <ProductType>
                    <HealthMisc>
                        <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
                        <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
                    </HealthMisc>
                </ProductType>
            </Health>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Then I tried to GetSubmissionList() it returned me firstly status of request as *SUBMIT* then *DONE*. But I can't find where it added. There is no product in my shop, though I had inserted my credentials in request. Actually, GetFeedSubmissionResult() returns nothing. Where is my fault and to what place it adds?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I tried to insert instead fiction data data of real product and it works. So the correct xml request is 
And mercahnt identifier is mercant id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>RO7WA11930KB1CASA</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>UPC</Type>
                <Value>4015643103921</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Example Product Title</Title>
                <Brand>Example Product Brand</Brand>
                <Description>This is an example product description.</Description>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
                <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
                <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
                <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Health>
                    <ProductType>
                        <HealthMisc>
                            <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
                            <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
                        </HealthMisc>
                    </ProductType>
                </Health>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

As a result - new product added to Inventary

Comment: Hi, where can I find the documentation for inserting products into my amazon account using a products feeds?

Comment: Is there any method to get product id from amazon after submit this product?

Comment: good explanation. I want to know that supposes product already selling in amazon and I want also sell that product then I also need to send same AmazonEnvelope xml ? and pass ASIN in value  <StandardProductID>          <Type>ASIN</Type> <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value> </StandardProductID> ? and what If product not exists in amazon ?

Comment: Hi how to get the product data and product type according to the category selected.? can you please help me to find this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619808/how-to-get-product-data-and-product-type-in-amazon

Answer (score 0):

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf

see page no. 39 for data object for adding new product.

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/use-case-guides/feeds-api-use-case-guide/feeds-api-use-case-guide-2020-09-04.md

and this for the stepwise process of creating the feed.